# how to fix USB ports unusable, xhci_hcd driver failing at boot?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, kernel, xhci-hcd

**Hardware**: MSI Stealth laptop with Intel I7 CPU, and nvidia RTX 3080.

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04.3 - kernel 5.13.0-30-generic

This problem has been reported by a few others with varying suggestions for a fix, none of which work for me.  In my case, the problem began as an intermittent problem that would reset to a working state after multiple reboots.  After recent upgrades, the problem is now permanent.

I don't believe the problem to be related to the BIOS or hardware because I can boot to a live USB (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - Kernel 5.11.0-27-generic) and all USB ports are usable.  The following is the state of the system **when USB ports are usable**

```
~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 5, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 6, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 4, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=rndis_host, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

The install system's usb list looks like this:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
```

These are my USB controllers:

```
~$ lsmod | grep hcd; lspci -nnk | grep "USB controller" -A2
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:06ed]
        DeviceName: Onboard - Other
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:12ed]
--
3a:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e9] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [1462:12ed]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

These are the relevant dmesg lines:

```
[   12.088461] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
[   12.088470] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   12.088476] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
[   12.088541] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
...
[   12.088461] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
[   12.088470] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   12.088476] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
[   12.088541] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
```

Some of the suggested fixes on-line involved unbind/bind of the devices in /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/, but this did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.  Without USB my laptop is a brick.

Thanks

Additional Edit

```
# dpkg --list | grep linux-
ii  binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu                                  2.34-6ubuntu1.3                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for aarch64-linux-gnu target
ii  binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                2.34-6ubuntu1.3                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for arm-linux-gnueabihf target
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                                   2.34-6ubuntu1.3                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  cpp-9-aarch64-linux-gnu                                     9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                   9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu                                       4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                      amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp) for the arm64 architecture
ii  cpp-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                      amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp) for the armhf architecture
ii  g++-9-aarch64-linux-gnu                                     9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GNU C++ compiler (cross compiler for arm64 architecture)
ii  g++-aarch64-linux-gnu                                       4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                      amd64        GNU C++ compiler for the arm64 architecture
ii  gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu                                     9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GNU C compiler (cross compiler for arm64 architecture)
ii  gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu-base:amd64                          9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                   9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GNU C compiler (cross compiler for armhf architecture)
ii  gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base:amd64                        9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04cross2           amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu                                       4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                      amd64        GNU C compiler for the arm64 architecture
ii  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                      amd64        GNU C compiler for the armhf architecture
ii  linux-base                                                  4.5ubuntu3.7                          all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                              1.187.26                              all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                                     5.13.0.30.33~20.04.17                 amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic                             5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-46-generic                             5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic                             5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic                             5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic                              5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04                             5.13.0.30.33~20.04.17                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-27                            5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-46                            5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-28                            5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30                            5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63                              5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic                               5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic                               5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic                               5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-36-generic                               5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic                               5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic                               5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic                               5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic                               5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic                               5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic                               5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic                               5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic                               5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic                               5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic                               5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic                                5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-50-generic                                5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic                                5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic                                5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic                                5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic                                5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04                               5.13.0.30.33~20.04.17                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
rc  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.1-051101-generic                  5.11.1-051101.202103031212            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.1 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                                        5.4.0-100.113                         amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross                                  5.4.0-59.65cross1                     all          Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
ii  linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross                                  5.4.0-59.65cross1                     all          Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic                             5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.11.0-27-generic                             5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-34-generic                             5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-36-generic                             5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-37-generic                             5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic                             5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic                             5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-41-generic                             5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-43-generic                             5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic                             5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic                             5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.1-051101-generic                         5.11.1-051101.202103031212            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.1 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.13.0-27-generic                             5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.13.0-28-generic                             5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic                             5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic                              5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-50-generic                              5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic                              5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-55-generic                              5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-59-generic                              5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-63-generic                              5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic                       5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-27-generic                       5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-34-generic                       5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-36-generic                       5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-37-generic                       5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic                       5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-40-generic                       5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-41-generic                       5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-43-generic                       5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-44-generic                       5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-46-generic                       5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic                       5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic                       5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic                       5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic                        5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-50-generic                        5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic                        5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-55-generic                        5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-59-generic                        5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-63-generic                        5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-25-generic                  5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1+3                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-25
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-27-generic                  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-34-generic                  5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-34
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-36-generic                  5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-36
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-37-generic                  5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-37
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-38-generic                  5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-38
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-43-generic                   5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-43
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-50-generic                   5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1+1                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-50
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-53-generic                   5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-53
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-55-generic                   5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-55
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-59-generic                   5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-59
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.13.0-28-generic                  5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+2                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.13.0-30-generic                  5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-30
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04                  5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-510 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-25-generic                  5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1+3                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-25 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-27-generic                  5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-27 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-34-generic                  5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-34 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-36-generic                  5.11.0-36.40~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-36 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-37-generic                  5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-37 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-38-generic                  5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-38 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.8.0-50-generic                   5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1+1                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-50 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.8.0-53-generic                   5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-53 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.8.0-55-generic                   5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-55 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.8.0-59-generic                   5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-59 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic                  5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.11.0-40 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-28-generic                  5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+2                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-510-5.13.0-28-generic                  5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+2                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-510-5.13.0-30-generic                  5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-30 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-28-generic                   5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+2                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-30-generic                   5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-30-generic
ii  linux-sound-base                                            1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  nsight-graphics-for-embeddedlinux-2021.2.1                  2021.2.1                              amd64        NVIDIA Nsight Graphics is a standalone application for the debugging, profiling, and analysis of graphics applications.
ii  syslinux-common                                             3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                                             2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                  amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
```

Comment: Do they work if you boot to the previous kernel in the grub boot options?

Comment: Just tried that.  Booted to 5.13.0-28-generic with the same results.  I don't have any earlier kernels to try unless I revert install

Comment: If you have a working internet connection, you can install previous kernels.  You know it loads with kernel `5.11.0-27-generic` that the Live USB has.  You install it with `sudo apt install linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-27-generic`  Then reboot and select it.  Hard to say, but they are showing that the xHCI_HCD driver is supposed to be in kernel 5.13.  Maybe the 5.13 kernel isn't setup right.  Maybe the modules are missing from the 5.13 kernel `sudo apt install linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic`

Comment: thanks for that suggestion.  I've install 5.11.0-27.  The good news is that USB is back!  The bad news is that ethernet is gone.   I'm investigating....

Comment: after rebooting back to 5.13.0.30 both ethernet and USB work.  While I'm happy the system is back, I'm not happy that I don't know why.   I'm not sure what will fix it next time.  Downgrading to an earlier kernel, then booting back to the current kernel feels  a little like an incantation.

Comment: Did you notice if it installed anything extra for 5.13 kernel when you installed the 5.11 kernel?

Comment: I'm afraid I did not notice.  I may be back to the intermittent state that started this whole investigation, which leaves me afraid to reboot.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1394331/edit) your question and add in the output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-`?

Comment: done @Terrance.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess I forgot to tell you to install `linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-27-generic` as well for the 5.11 kernel.  Which one are you currently booted into?  I am not seeing anything jumping out at me that would be missing from any of the other 5.13 kernels that would stop the USB from working.  I guess you can try installing the extra modules I have stated above and you can try to see if the 5.11 kernel is more stable.

Comment: Thanks, Terrance.  I'll give that a shot.   I'm currently booted into 5.13.0-30-generic.